# Nikon p900 Bracketing and Timer

Tags: nikon, bracketing, self-timer, nikon-p900

I have a Nikon p900.   I want to use bracketed exposures along with either a timer or remote shutter.   Activating anything off the timer menu, either a 2 second timer or selecting the shutter remote turns off bracketing.   Is there really no way to use bracketing with a timer or remote?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there really no way to use bracketing with a timer or remote?

No, there isn't. When using the self timer or remote control, with regard to Continuous/Exposure bracketing, page 47 of the [P900 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/rMezq00iFKyL03Mwu1F53Dc45i62/P900RM_(En)07.pdf) states:

> - When self-timer/remote control is used, a single image is shot even if Continuous H, Continuous L, Pre- shooting cache, or BSS has been set. If Intvl timer shooting is set, shooting finishes automatically after one image is shot.
> - Exposure bracketing is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I was also frustrated by the inability to shoot a bracket set with a timer or remote control on Nikon DSLRs. I started using my compact Lumix LX10 for HDR bracket sets which will shoot the bracket set using the 2 sec delay.  Come on Nikon! The solution for Nikon I found was to use a wired remote. It works as if it was the shutter button on the camera, ie hold down and it will shoot the bracket set and stop.  The Nikon one is crazy expensive but you can find them very cheaply on Amazon or the like for around $10 to $45. The latter being an intervalarometer too if that is required. Importantly the basic function of shutter release is actually powered from the camera via the connection.  Check with the unit you buy and do your research but the cheap single function ones probably won't need batteries to do what you want. It's essential just a switch. I bought a multi function one with interval functions which requires batteries but it will still fire the shutter without the batteries. It cost around $25. I hope this helps.